# C - Divide array into threads and find max number using parallelism

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, openmp, pragma

I have an array of random numbers and I need to divide it into 4 threads and then find the max number in the array using parallelism. I'm new to working with threads and I have few knowledge of the pragma functions. However, I tried with the next code.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <omp.h>
#define N 10000
int searchMax(int *a, int n){
    int max, i;
    max = a[0]; 
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
        #pragma omp critical 
        { 
            if (a[i] > max) 
            max = a[i]; 
        } 
    }
    return(max);
}
int main(){
    int i, arr[N], max; 
    time_t t; 
    clock_t tini, tfin; 
    double tdur;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        arr[i] = rand();
        tini = clock(); 
        max = arr[0]; 
        for (i = 1; i < N; i++) 
            if (arr[i] > max) 
                max = arr[i]; 
        tini = clock();
        max = searchMax(arr, N); 
        tfin = clock(); 
        tdur = (double)(tfin - tini) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
        printf("max number: %d time: %lf\n", max, tdur);
        return(0);
    }
```

The thing is that this code only divides the for loop. I don't know how to divide the array into threads and make each of them do the for loop.

Comment: Seing that the critical section makes all of the loop code that would be put in thread, you would have very little gain from the parallelism. I would suggest taking a divide and conquer approach, but even then the gain would be minimal.

Comment: In shared-memory parallel computing, such as OpenMP is used for, you *don't* divide the array across the threads - each thread has the same access to it.  As you've written your code each thread gets its own subset of the values of `i` to work with, and therefore a set of elements of `a`. Now refer to your tutorial and reference material to learn how to use OpenMP for *reductions* (on the *max* operator specifically), and to learn about *shared* and *private* variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let OpenMP divide the array into threads for you, no need to worry about -- ok to be fair, OpenMP will divide the array iteration space among the threads not the array itself.

I believe that you can use the reduction clause here as shown below. By using the reduction clause -- in this particular case --, each thread will keep the maximum value (into `maxvalue`) and at the end of the parallel region they will choose the maximum value from among the values found by every thread. This way, you can avoid using the critical clause and the `#pragma omp parallel for` will distribute the array among threads for you.

```
int searchMax(int *a, int n){
    int maxvalue, i;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(max: maxvalue)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > maxvalue)
            maxvalue = a[i];
    }
    return maxvlue;
}
```

Comment: And if I need specifically 4 threads to do the work, should I just add num_threads(4) ?? Or will it cause conflict with any of the other directives?

Comment: You can add num_threads(4) to the #pragma clause if you want because they are orthogonal. However, by doing that you're limiting the amount of parallelism there -- especially if you run on a high core-count processor.